# correct way to pass errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form in a view of my project and

Im doing

```
redirect_to root_path(@locale), alert: @client.errors
```

and getting the errors in my view iterating with

```
flash[:alert].full_messages.each
```

but when there are a lot of errors rails launch the error

```
ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow
```

what is the correct way to pass a lot of error descriptions in RoR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the alert is a set length string - not something that can grow this long.

```
render :new, alert: "There has been an error"
```

When you render you can look for the errors in an instance object - in this case @client.errors.

The rails way is something like this in the view...

```
<% if @client.errors %>
  <ul>
    <% @client.errors.full_messages.each do |m| %>
      <li><%= m %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Forgive my erb - I've been writing haml too long.

The main thing to take away from this is to render instead of redirect.  Usually the page that's rendered is the same one that had the form.  So, in the create method, you render new on error.  In the update method, you render edit.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think that the most correct way to pass error is to use a `redirect_to` only if you pass the validation, and a `render` if you don't (a simple test on the value of `@object.update_attributes(hash)`).

This way, you can directly access your object errors from inside your view (through `@object.errors`) without loading anything in the user cookies.